# Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side. What does this mean?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, vector

Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side. What does this mean?

Error in 
    segment(n_start)=data(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1));

```
%% input data matrix
DDD=load('data2.mat');
data=DDD.data;
N_max=length(data);
window_size=256*3; %% 256 for 1 second ==> 3 seconds
step_win=128*3; %% overlapping window ...by 50%
segment=zeros(4798,768);
count=0;
for n_start = 1:step_win:(N_max-window_size)
    count=count+1;
    segment(n_start)=data(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1));
end
plot(Segment)
xlabel('time')
grid on;
title('data of channel1');
```

Comment: You don't say *where* you got the error (always include the entire error message), but I assume it's on the line assigning `Segment(n_start)` where you're trying to fit a 768-element vector into a single array element. I don't think that's what you want to do. Also, you should check your variable names. You initialize `segment` but assign `Segment`. Those are not the same.

Comment: I want the array `segment=zeros(4798,768)` to be filled each time the loop iterate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the passage:

```
segment(n_start)=data(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1));
```

You are attempting to attribute a vector into a 1x1 matrix.

If `segment` is a vector, then `segment(n_start)` is its value at the location `n_start`, if `n_start` in an integer, then `segment(n_start)` is 1x1.

On the other hand `n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1)` is a vector that spans from `n_start` and increases one by one until `(n_start+ window_size-1)`. And that due to how the `:` operator works. Because `window_size=256*3`, then it is a 767-long vector.

When you call `data(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1))`, you are asking all the values of data in the indexes contained in the vector `n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1)`.

Hence, in the error line, you trying to atribute a vector of size 767x1 to a 1x1 matrix. that is why it doesn't work.

Comment: OK thank you i understood. Do you have any recommendations to solve this problem? I want the array segment=zeros(4798,768) to be filled each time the loop iterate. 4798 is the number of segments and 768 is the number of elements in each segment

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want, but notice you can make: `segment(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1))=data(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1));`. This will overwrite fields that have been written before. You could also consider: `segment(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1))= segment(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1)) + data(n_start:(n_start+ window_size-1));`